# Cloud Foundry - Rails 4 database.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloud-foundry

I am trying to deploy my Rails 4 app which uses a mysql database.  The database is hosted on a different server.

I am confused as how my database.yml file should be configured, and how does cloud foundry know which section to use.

After deployment, I get this error when loading my app

```
ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified
'' database is not configured. Available: ["development"]

Rails.root: /home/vcap/app
```

If you then refresh the page, you get:

```
NoMethodError
undefined method `default_timezone=' for #<Class:0x007fd7930ab0f0>

Rails.root: /home/vcap/app
```

My database.yml is like this:

```
#local development
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  host: hostname
  port: 3306
  database: appdb
  username: myapp
  password: 'password'
  timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test: &test
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000


production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  host: hostname
  port: 3306
  database: appdb
  username: myapp
  password: 'password'
  timeout: 5000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed this in application.rb:

ENV['DATABASE_URL'] = 'mysql2://username:password@hostname:3306/dbname'

Answer (score 0):

If you running the rails app in production mode. The configuration would something like that.

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: rails_myapp
  username: rails_myapp_user
  password: pwd
  host: 128.199.233.36
  port: 5432
  pool: 10
```

Comment: I am deploying to a dev environment on an internal hosted CF.  How does it know what to use>

Comment: how does cloud foundry know which entry to use form the database.yml file

Comment: Didn't you set the environment at first while you deploying the app? There is command called `RAILS_ENV=production`. When you set it the system automatically know which db configuration call you. is it `development` or `production` config? okay.

Answer (score 0):

Consider setting the database url as an environment variable in CF:

`cf set-env <app-name> DATABASE_URL 'mysql2://username:password@hostname:3306/dbname'`